# « rater » et « perdre »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

J'ai commencé à jouer sur des sites en langue française et l'expression que le site utilise quand un joueur n'a pas eu de succès est « vous avez perdu ». Pourtant, je sais qu'il y a le verbe *rater* qui, dans les dictionnaires que j'ai pu consulter, est traduit en italien de la même façon que *perdre*.

Puisque je n'ai pas de dictionnaires avancés, je voudrais savoir si l'on peut dire « perdre/rater une opportunité » (je n'ai jamais vu ce verbe utilisé pour des compétitions). Est-ce que *rater* a peut-être une signification similaire à *waste* en anglais ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans ce cas *rater* signifie *manquer* au sens de *manquer une cible*, par extension, quand on perd à un jeu, on peut dire qu'on a raté. Cependant, dans ce cas, *rater* est plutôt familier et peut être considéré par certains comme impoli. Dans le contexte d'un jeu en ligne, il est donc plus normal de dire *perdu*.

En ce qui concerne les opportunités, on peut effectivement dire qu'on les manque ou qu'on les perd, avec une légère différence de sens, je comprends « j'ai perdu une opportunité » comme « j'ai essayé et j'ai échoué » et « J'ai manqué une opportunité » comme « je ne savais pas qu'il y avait une opportunité ».

Enfin, non, *rater* n'a pas le même sens que *waste*. *Waste* se traduirait plutôt par *gâcher*. Et on peut aussi dire qu'on *gâche* une opportunité, ce qui a le même sens que *perdre une oportunité*.

Answer (score 1):

*Perdre* est l'opposé de *gagner*. Dans un jeu où il y a une compétition ou une opposition, il y a les gagnants (avec parfois pour synonyme *vainqueur*) et les perdants.

*Rater* est synonyme de *manquer* ou d'*échouer*. Dans les jeux sans opposition (même pas représentée par l'ordinateur, p.e. le démineur), on *réussit* ou on *rate*.

Edit: translate.google suggère aussi *mancare* pour rater, suggestion qui est absente pour *perdre* (et qui doit avoir la même étymologie que *manquer*).  Puisque tu fais référence à l'anglais, il y a la même différence entre *perdre* et *rater* en français qu'entre *to loose* et *to fail* en anglais.  *to waste* est plus proche de *perdre* (et ça ne m'étonnerait pas que dans certains contextes on puisse traduire *to waste* par *perdre*, ou le nom *waste* par *perte*).

Comment: Mais quand j'ai vérifié avec Google Translate les traductions anglaises de "rater", j'ai trouvé comme premier example "miss", qui en anglais peut être utilisé pour ne pas prendre le bus comme pour sentir le manque de quelqu'un. C'est pour ça que je n'arrive pas à bien comprendre la différence.

Comment: @Paola, _Traduttore traditore_. Oui, il y a des contextes où _rater_ (comme _manquer_ d'ailleurs) peut se traduire par _to miss_ en anglais. Il est rare que deux mots de langues différentes soient à employer toujours l'un pour l'autre.

Comment: comme il est vrai! On n'est jamais certains de la signification d'un mot s'il on considère seulement le dictionnaire. Je le sais très bien pour ce qui concerne l'anglais, mais malheureusement je ne utilise pas le français si frequemment pour avoir appris les nuances à travers l'usage. Merci de vos réponses.